# My component is not rendering, why?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm quite new to React and after trying for some long hours I haven't been able to add a component inside the main app js

I created my boilerplate with create-react-app

In the main app.js I have:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import casa_mini from './casa_mini'; 
import './App.css';



class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<casa_mini></casa_mini>    );
    }
}

export default App;
```

And in the casa_mini.js I have:

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';

class casa_mini extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <div className="listing-box">
                <div className="listing-box-image" style={{backgroundImage: 'url("assets/img/casa1.jpg")'}}>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default casa_mini;
```

Why its not rendering anything? the HTML of casa_mini doesn't appear.. blank page.. Thanks for the help!

---

Comment: you must tell what is the error before we can point out where is the error

Comment: Check the browser console output. Is there any error? Are there any build errors?

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay true!! I just edited it.. the html of casa_mini.js doesnt appear

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for some fast answers.. the problem is the capital letter of the component..

```
index.js: Warning: The tag <casa_mini> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
```

It should be capitalized!